# Is it possible to create a Vertex that requires an edge in order to be created

Tags: constraints, orientdb

I'd like to know if it is possible to create a Vertex that requires an edge in order to be created.

For example, I want to create an `Invoice` class that has a `HasCustomer` edge which points to Person.

I want the `HasCustomer` edge to be mandatory in order to create the Invoice.

You cannot create the `Invoice` unless you have the `HasCustomer` edge.

I know we can have a `link to Person`, but there is no referential integrity. I can delete the `Person and the Invoice` will simply end up with a link to a customer that is non-existent.

Comment: That's a great question! I hope someone can help you with the answer.

Comment: @OutfastSource Thanks, hope we get the answer

Comment: I think this answer gives a clue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274362/is-it-possible-to-constraint-edge-multiplicity-in-neo4j-orientdb/26278502#26278502 The element I'm interested in is the MIN constraint for a property. The problem I've encountered in working with this though is that the vertex needs to exist first and then the edge, or you have to create the edge and the 2 vertexes at the same time. By having the min on the vertex, the edge needs to be passed into the create vertex which I think is impossible.

Comment: That isn't what the OP asked for, is it? He wants to be able to create a Vertex and have an Edge automatically created due to the Vertrex creation. This simply isn't possible with OOTB ODB. 

What you've gotten on to is edge multiplicity. This is possible, but not with property constraints as in the answer you linked to. Getting a unidirectional edge is better done with a unique index constraint (currently). See here: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Tutorial-Using-schema-with-graphs.html

Answer (score 1):

In OrientDB, you have to create the edge yourself. So if you have the invoice vertex created, you then have to create the HasCustomer edge between the invoice and the customer.

However, if you delete that invoice vertex later, ODB will also remove the linked edge you created (and others) automatically, in order to keep up the data integrity (i.e no orphaned edges).

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Delete-Vertex.html

This is also why you should choose the Graph API over the Document API. With the Document API, keeping up any integrity between links is up to you.

I am also not sure if it is possible, but you could theoretically create a server-side function, which triggers after any invoice vertex is created (onAfterCreation trigger), which could then create the HasCustomer edge automatically. Again, all theory on my part, as I've never done it before.

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Functions.html
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Dynamic-Hooks.html

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Watching the official documentation, you can't do the operation that you have described. The only property mandatory you can use is on the fields on class or on edges. About use of the link, rightly as you said, missing control over referential integrity, this because to do this check is very expensive in terms of performance.